# Loop through a dictionary collection to search a key and increase value

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a dictionary that I put in session and on each button click I need to perform some operation.

```
itemColl = new Dictionary<int, int>();
```

I want to search for a key that I maintain in a session variable, if the key exist then I want to increase the value by 1 for the corresponding key, how can I achive this.

I am trying it as follows:

```
if (Session["CurrCatId"] != null)
{
    CurrCatId = (int)(Session["CurrCatId"]);
    // this is the first time, next time i will fetch from session
    // and want to search the currcatid and increase the value from
    // corresponding key by 1.
    itemColl = new Dictionary<int, int>();
    itemColl.Add(CurrCatId, 1);
    Session["itemColl"] = itemColl;                            
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're pretty close, you just need to manage a few more cases:

```
if (Session["CurrCatId"] != null)
{
    CurrCatId = (int)(Session["CurrCatId"]);

    // if the dictionary isn't even in Session yet then add it
    if (Session["itemColl"] == null)
    {
        Session["itemColl"] = new Dictionary<int, int>();
    }

    // now we can safely pull it out every time
    itemColl = (Dictionary<int, int>)Session["itemColl"];

    // if the CurrCatId doesn't have a key yet, let's add it
    // but with an initial value of zero
    if (!itemColl.ContainsKey(CurrCatId))
    {
        itemColl.Add(CurrCatId, 0);
    }

    // now we can safely increment it
    itemColl[CurrCatId]++;
}
```

Comment: what is itemCol1, and this statement for itemCol1[CurrCatId]++;

Comment: @NoviceToDotNet, and the `itemColl[CurrCatId]++` provides you this `if the key exist then I want to increase the value by 1`.

Comment: @NoviceToDotNet, I have no idea what you mean by that then. I need you to ***very clearly*** define what you want. The `key` of a dictionary is the *left-hand side* of the `Dictionary<int, int>`. You want to increment that???

Comment: i see you are increasing the key value itself, not the value of a key, that you set to 0 for forst time that i want to increase by 1 next time if key exist..i want to increase the right hand side..

Comment: @NoviceToDotNet, your original code did this the first time through `itemColl.Add(CurrCatId, 1);`, thus setting the ***initial value if it didn't already exist*** to `1`. Well, I refactored that to streamline it so I didn't have to do as much `if...else` and so I set the ***initial value*** to `0` and then I increment on the following statement -thus providing you with the same outcome as your original example.

Comment: @NoviceToDotNet, and `itemColl[CurrCatId]++;` increments the ***value*** of that ***key***, or the *right-hand side of the `Dictionary`*.

Comment: i want  itemColl.Add(CurrCatId, 0); 0 to increase by one if i find the key again, in my case i want 1 to increase by 1 that i want next time it to set 2 if again i find the key i want it to set 3 like that sir..

Comment: @NoviceToDotNet, that's what `itemColl[CurrCatId]++;` does.

Comment: @NoviceToDotNet, and if you want `0 to increase by one if i find the key again`, ***which does not match the logic in your question***, then put the increment in an `else` -pretty simple.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** sorry, I hadn't understood the question before. You simply try to use that key, like this:

```
try
{
    if (condition)
        itemColl[i]++;
}
catch
{
    // ..snip
}
```

Use a `try-catch` so that if for some reason the key isn't there, you can handle the error.

Comment: using exceptions for something like this is overkill. Dictionary offers nice methods for this, like `ContainsKey` and `TryGetValue`, depending on what you need. Better to stick to them - easier to read and probably better performance.

Answer (score 1):

```
var itemColl = Session["itemColl"];
if (!itemColl.ContainsKey(CurrCatId))
    itemColl[CurrCatId] = 0;
itemColl[CurrCatId]++;
```